# What are Cocoa Touch UIKit Layouts out there

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit

I couldn't find Cocoa Touch docs for UIKit layouts for iOS application. Is there a page where I can read all types of layouts Apple has developed for developers to use?

I like Google docs about Android as how clear they put all types of layouts like RelativeLayout, LinearLayout etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Apple's UIKit documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/_index.html) – it contains all the information on what's available within the UIKit for Cocoa Touch.

> The UIKit framework provides the classes needed to construct and manage an application’s user interface for iOS. It provides an application object, event handling, drawing model, windows, views, and controls specifically designed for a touch screen interface. Figure I-1 illustrates the classes in this framework.

Also check out [UIKit at CocoaDev](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/UIKit) - they have tutorials as well as crowd-sourced documentation.